# how to Control "Windows XP Volume Control" with VC#

Tags: c#, winforms

i want to write know how to control "Windows XP Volume Control" (volume, wave, cd sound ) using VC# Winforms. and what ever the method will it also work for windows Vista is compile my code with a third party software to make EXE code instead of ClR code that is dependent on .NET.