# How can I control system sound volume with a TrackBar?

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I'm a beginner and making an internet radio player and I want to control the volume with my own `TrackBar`. How is that possible? I haven't found any solutions to do this.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139181/how-to-programmatically-set-the-system-volume

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8192953/1577396

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at NAudio. this is a brilliant API for implementing audio based applications in .NET

http://naudio.codeplex.com/

Also consider this

[how to Control "Windows XP Volume Control" with VC#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361844/how-to-control-windows-xp-volume-control-with-vc?rq=1)

This might also help. This explains how to hook the Win32 API Multimedia library (winmm.dll) to control system volume

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/

Comment: Thanks for these. Im continuing learning because this is quite hard for me now.

Comment: @Burucsb, learning is your key to success, and it gets easier with time! :-)