# Set volume up or down 10% and full and mute c#

Tags: c#, volume

To increase and decrease the volume I use this code (c#):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

keybd_event((byte)Keys.VolumeUp, 0, 0, 0); // increase volume
keybd_event((byte)Keys.VolumeDown, 0, 0, 0); // decrease volume
```

How can I raise and lower the volume by 10% and How I can mute or set to full volume?
I use a loop to decrease and increase the volume But I do not think that's the right way.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the language you're using and the framework you're using. No-one will find your question otherwise with such a generic tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I control system sound volume with a TrackBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232085/how-can-i-control-system-sound-volume-with-a-trackbar)

Answer (score -1):

This example is from a speech recognition system I'm designing in C#.  The first image is your **Variable Declarations**, this is a vital part to fulfill first. This goes just under the top of your project/code (**Under Public Class Form**) -Void the Timer Declarations-
In the second image, you will see that I used a **Switch/Case** statement, which are similar to **If** & **Else** statements, both designed for executing one case at a time. You may very well be using something other than **Case** or **If** statements, and if that's the case, I would make your **cases** into a **function**, calling the **function** to satisfy certain conditions. I am essentially using an **Iteration Statement** as seen in the 2nd picture to produce 10 loops at once for my volume. I declared and initialize a local loop variable in that section.

[First Step/Public Class Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDpW4.png)

[2nd Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6gBW.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please refrain from posting images of your code and instead post them in code blocks.